# Спорный случай: нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, литература

Доброго времени суток!
Устроим минутку Данте: отвечая на один из вопросов здесь, стала искать цитату "Оставь надежду(,) всяк сюда входящий". Как выяснилось, написание разнится в источниках. В частности, та же Википедия дает такое:

> Оста́вь наде́жду, вся́к сюда́ входя́щий (итал. Lasciate ogni speranza, voi ch’entrate)

А на мой (и не только) взгляд, здесь действует правило, описанное Д.Э. Розенталем:

> Не являются обращениями и не выделяются запятыми названия
>   лица или предмета, находящиеся при форме повелительного
>   наклонения, если она употреблена в значении пожелания
>   («пусть...»), например: Приходи к нему лечиться и корова и волчица (К. Чуковский); Всяк сверчок знай свой шесток (пословица).

Т. е. я полагаю, что более верным будет написание без запятой.
Что думаете вы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надпись «**Оставь надежду всяк сюда входящий**» на вратах ада отражала главное свойство придуманной людьми обители мучений. [И. А. Ефремов. Час быка (1968-1969)]

Мне более правильным представляется этот вариант **(без запятой)**. Здесь нет паузы, да и понимание фразы в форме обращения кажется странным и немного примитивным.

Думаю, что постановка запятой связана с тем, что не была учтена **частная форма повелительного наклонения** ― "оставь" в значении "пусть оставит".

Answer (score 4):

Я согласна с двояким ответом Грамоты.ру:

> Фраза эта обычно приводится с запятой: слова всяк сюда входящий
>   обособляются как обращение (к тем, кто входит во врата ада). Но можно
>   обосновать и отсутствие запятой: запятую допустимо не ставить, если
>   считать, что в этой фразе заложено значение пожелания (пусть оставит
>   надежду всяк сюда входящий).